# $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic. Show that also their one-point compactifications are homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology

> Assume $X$ and $Y$ are two homeomorphic locally compact Hausdorff-spaces. Show that also their one-point compactifications are homeomorphic.
>
> Give an example of two non homeomorphic locally compact Hausdorff-spaces but which one-point compactifications are homeomorphic.

---

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two locally compact Hausdorff-spaces and
$f: X \rightarrow Y$ a homeomorphism. Define the two spaces
one-point compactifications as $X'$ and $Y'$ and call the
additional points $p$ and $q$.

Extend $f$ by letting $f(p) = q$.

To show that $f$ is a homeomorphism it is enough to show that
$f(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ are open in $Y'$ and $X'$ where
$U$ and $V$ are open neighborhoods of $p$ and $q$, respectively.

---

This is the first problem i am solving which deals with one-point compactifications.

I am not sure how to show this and also have difficulties
to come up with an example.

Any ideas?

**edit:**

First part is solved. Only the example they are looking for remains.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the topology on the one point compactification?

Comment: @LeeMosher  Yes i think i got it now.
You can write the open set $U$ 
in $X'$ as $\{p\} \cup (X \setminus K)$
where $K$ is compact and
then $f(U) = \{q\} \cup (Y \setminus f(K))$
is open.

Comment: Now only the example they are looking for remains.

Comment: How about $[0,1)$ vs. $[0,1) \sqcup (1,2]$?

Comment: @quartermind yeah, that should do it i think. It was easier than i thought :)  Thank you.